# Strange "Anonymous" user events showing up after node edit, diff, or save

Tags: rules, emails, nodes

So I'm not sure how to even ask this question or debug it, but it's causing quite an issue on our production and dev servers.  Normally we send out emails with diff information on them whenever a node is updated, saved, or new.  All of this is happening using Rules and the Diff module and helps let our team know when a node is getting new info added to it.

The strange part is that every time a node is changed we get one email from the user that changed it and then another email immediately after that has Anonymous set as posting a change.  Similarly if you go and check Diff on the live site it will show that Anonymous has logged a change even though nothing on the node has actually changed by Anonymous.

Permissions all are set correctly and I haven't seen any other information out there in the drupal world that is similar to this.  Does anyone konw why drupal would be logging Anonymous randomly on node changes?  Thanks, just stumped at where to begin.

Comment: You could have a rogue hook being called on node update that's not setting the uid correctly therefore showing up as anon. Are you running any custom modules?

Comment: Yes, I'm running a few actually.  Mostly to redirect a pop up for commerce as well as set a custom Title of the node.

Comment: I'd check in those to see if anything weird is going on. Failing that break out xdebug and loop through node_save to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: Great idea digital.  I'm picking up where another dev left off so I'm thinking xdebug is my only option... :(